# How to combine Prefetch with annotate and order_by annotated value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Anyone have idea how to make that query working ? I want to sort users by common rooms. It's possible to annotate prefetched value?

```
users.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'rooms',
            queryset=Room.objects.filter(participants__in=[user]),
            to_attr='common_rooms'
        ),
    ).annotate(
        common_rooms_count=Count('common_rooms')
    ).order_by(
        'common_rooms_count'
    )
```